# Set static point at near 100% X or Y axis in CSS Clip path

Tags: css, clip-path

I want to create clip path css with shape like folder. When I'm using this:

```
.frame-folder {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 7.5% 0%, 10% 7.5%, 100% 7.5%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-color: #000000
}
```

[image: Stretching points]
The points at the top will stretching when containing big content, so I'm using px for the solution:

```
.frame-folder {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 150px 0%, 200px 80px, 100% 80px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-color: #000000
}
```

[image: Static point]
But the problem is when I want to create folder shape but reverse in x axis. How I can set the static point at near 100% x or y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc()`

```css
.frame-folder {
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 150px) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80px, calc(100% - 200px) 80px);
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-folder"> </div>
```